# C++: Classes & Constructors: Using Initialization Lists to Initialize Fields

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

Full code. Line specified later.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class X
{
    private:

    int i;
    float f;
    char c;

    public:

    X(int first=1, float second=2.0, char third='a') : i(first) , f(second) , c(third) { } 
    void print() { cout << i << " " << f << " " << c << endl;}

};


int main()
{
    X var1;
    var1.print();

    return 0;
}
```

What exactly is going on on this line:

```
X(int first=1, float second=2.0, char third='a') : i(first) , f(second) , c(third) { }
```

As far as I can understand (could be wrong), we are declaring objects first, second, and third of type (class) X. We are initializing them during declaration. What's going on after the colon? What's going on altogether?

Comment: you should really specify the language here... ideally in a tag and the title.
Even so, this probably isn't the best question...

Comment: Sorry, will do from next time. Realized it after pressing the submit button.

Comment: Constructor initializer list is a basic feature of C++ language. This is something you read about in your favorite C++ book.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know the name of the topic, or what to look for exactly. Updated title for someone may search for it in future.

Answer (score 3):

What exactly is going on on this line:

```
X(int first=1, float second=2.0, char third='a') 
: i(first) , f(second) , c(third) { 
}
```

It's a constructor which takes 3 parameters with default values.

This part `: i(first) , f(second) , c(third)` is called a `member initializer list`.The member initializer list consists
of a comma-separated list of initializers preceded by a colon. It’s placed after the closing
parenthesis of the argument list and before the opening bracket of the function body.

Only constructors can use this initializer-list syntax. const class members must be initialized in member initializers.

Answer (score 2):

The stuff in the parenthesis are default values for the arguments to the constructor, and the stuff after the colon initializes those items after the colon.

The colon notation is most commonly used to invoke the constructors of other objects the class uses.

Comment: Is it equivalent to saying this: if we declare an object Y of type X, then Y.first will have default value 1, Y.second will have default value 2.0, Y.third will have default value a. After the colon, i is given the default value 1, f = 2.0, and c = a. So, in this case, is i(1) means i = 1?

Comment: Saying what?  I think your message got truncated.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Also keep in mind that default values for arguments (eg: first=1, etc...) can be used on any type of function.

Answer (score 2):

You have class X with three fields: i, f, c. 
You have defined a constructor with three default parameters - when this constructor invoked  fields are initialized with parameters (passed to constructor or defaults).
It's like:

```
X (int first=1, float second=2.0, char third='a')
{
   i = first;
   f = second;
   c = third;
}
```

Your line is just an another way to initialize fields, usually they are equal (there are some differences with inheritance).

In your main code you're creating a local variable `var1` of type X, so the constructor is called. You don't pass any parameters, so default values are used.

As result, you have **one** local object of type X initialized with default values listed in constructor.

Answer (score 1):

```
X(int first=1, float second=2.0, char third='a') : i(first) , f(second) , c(third) { }
```

This is a constructor for X. There are three agruments, each having a default value so that it can be invoked in different ways

```
X myX;
X myX(first);
X myX(first, second);
X myX(first, second, third);
```

The section after the arguments

```
: i(first) , f(second) , c(third)
```

are initializers for the `i`, `f` and `c` members. If possible this style of initialization is preferred over initialization in the function body, and if the members are constant types, this style is required.

Then there is an empty body for the constructor `{}`